# Where are VRMs on this Asus M5A78L-M/USB3 motherboard?

Tags: motherboard, cooling

I am planning to move an [Asus M5A78L-M/USB3](https://www.asus.com/us/Motherboards/M5A78LMUSB3/specifications/) and its [FX-6350](https://www.amd.com/en/products/cpu/fx-6350) CPU (default TDP 125W, max temp 61C) into a new chassis with a GeForce 1070 and a 680W power supply, but based on remarks here and elsewhere, I am concerned about the need to cool the Voltage Regulation Modules better than passive convection would provide.

[Where on that board](https://www.asus.com/media/global/products/2TinR0vmf3nCJ2GF/0C1MQvukzDOj3GQg_500.jpg) are the Voltage Regulators, so I can heatsink and fan-cool those for greater stability?  The circled yellow area?

[image]